# Can I display the .Net MAUI composed appicon in a specific (non-default) position?

Tags: .net, maui, appicon

I'm just migrating an app from Xamarin to .Net MAUI. I have no problem displaying "images" anywhere I like at a specific requested size etc. However, I would like to display the *default AppIcon* at various specific locations in my app - eg custom title bar, custom menu bar etc, but I can't work out how to do it; every time I reference it I just get a blank space, albeit at the requested height.

The instructions say

"*.NET MAUI converts SVG files to Portable Network Graphic (PNG) files. Therefore, when adding an SVG file to your .NET MAUI app project, it should be referenced from XAML or C# with a .png extension. The only reference to the SVG file should be in your project file.*"

My appicon is made up of SVG background and foreground files and works fine as a standard appicon for Windows, ioS and Android where it shows up in the expected places. But surely I can use it at a place of my choosing? Or do I have to create my own version, in all the different sizes necessary for different playforms etc as in the bad old days of Xamarin?

`Image Source="appicon.png"` - blank is displayed
`Image source="some other image.png"` - works as expected

Answer (score 0):

When you display an image its build action should be MauiImage whereas incase of AppIcon this is MauiIcon, so the behaviour is as expected

If you want this to work add another SVG that has both foreground and background together and then use that make sure build action is MauiIcon

Comment: Thanks a lot, I *sort of* understand I think, but it just seems a little odd. If I specify a Build Action of MAUIICON then I can no longer access the icon for my own ends? 

I'll check this out now. If I specify SVG background and foreground with build action of MAUIIMAGE, does it stil magically produce a PNG file as it apparently does for icon, or not?

Confusing!

Comment: It will not glue them together, you will need a separate image that has both together

Comment: Thanks @FreakyAli - I think the penny has finally dropped!

Comment: I am guessing it worked

Comment: I wouldn't say "worked" is the right answer in this weird alternative world, but I have got past my obstacle - thanks!

Comment: Whatever floats your boat man

Answer (score 0):

The maui icon consists of two files, `appicon.svg` and `appiconfg.svg`, where `appicon.svg` is the purple background and `appiconfg.svg` is the white `".net"` text.

So you can use `appiconfg.png` in the xaml file as shown in the code below and add purple background color to it to achieve your requirement.

```
<Image
    Source="appiconfg.png"
    BackgroundColor="#512BD4">
```

Also note that after adding the `appiconfg.svg` image to the resources/images folder, you need to set its `BuildAction` property to `MauiImage`.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me. As I said in the original post,

Image Source="appicon.png" - blank is displayed 
Image source="some other image.png" - works as expected

The composed appicon DOES appear in all the expected 'automatic' places.

I've copied appicon.svg and appiconfg.svg to Resources/Images and specified the BuildAction as MAUIIMAGE, but then I either get the background alone, if I specify source=appicon.png, or the foreground alone if I specify appiconfg.png!

Should I be specifying type <MauiIcon> or <MauiImage> instead of <Image>? The Maui types say "not found"